# Elastic TransportClient : too many TCP connections

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm using **Elastic 5.0**. I have a service that connects to several ES cluster and keeps the connection open. To do so, I'm using the [Transport Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/5.0/transport-client.html), and I have activated the sniffing so I have a code that looks a little bit like this

`val esSettings = Settings.builder()
      .put("cluster.name", "someName")
      .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
      .build()`

`val esClient = new TransportClient(esSettings, somePlugins) {}`

When I do a netstat on the instance running that service, I can see that I keep 14 TCP connections open per data node. Below is an example of all the connections made to the data node with IP 10.0.194.179

`tcp6       0      0 10.0.199.18:44188       10.0.194.179:9300       ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 10.0.199.18:44184       10.0.194.179:9300       ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 10.0.199.18:44187       10.0.194.179:9300       ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 10.0.199.18:44183       10.0.194.179:9300       ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 10.0.199.18:44189       10.0.194.179:9300       ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 10.0.199.18:44329       10.0.194.179:9300       ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 10.0.199.18:44192       10.0.194.179:9300       ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 10.0.199.18:44185       10.0.194.179:9300       ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 10.0.199.18:44186       10.0.194.179:9300       ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 10.0.199.18:44193       10.0.194.179:9300       ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 10.0.199.18:44181       10.0.194.179:9300       ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 10.0.199.18:44182       10.0.194.179:9300       ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 10.0.199.18:44190       10.0.194.179:9300       ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 10.0.199.18:44191       10.0.194.179:9300       ESTABLISHED -`

The 14 connections come from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/modules-threadpool.html) (generic, index, search ...)

Since I keep connections open to many clusters and that each cluster has many data nodes, it's reaching the limits of open TCP connection the OS can handle.

In my specific case, I only need a subset of the functionalities provided by the [ThreadPool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/modules-threadpool.html) (search, get, bulk).

Is there any way I could get a trimmed version of the ThreadPool, or any other way to reduce the numbers of active TCP connection?